# Buffer overrun detected

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I have an one question when I use C# DllImport C++ dll, I use the visual studio 2010 & checked the "Enable unmanaged code debugging", when it's running, always show the message "Buffer overrun detected! ... A buffer overrun has been detected which has corrupted the program's internal state. The program cannot safely continue execution and must now be terminated."

This dll is Third-party vendors to provide, and they says it's no error to run this dll, how can i fixed it?

My M++ dll function is,

```
int  avc_to_avi_convert(char* chPath_avc, char* chPath_avi, int pPrivate, PROGRESS_CALLBACK progress_callback);

void avc_to_avi_close(int* pFd_avi);

typedef void (*PROGRESS_CALLBACK)(int iPercent, int pPrivate);
```

And i am use it in my C# dllimport like this :

```
public delegate void PROGRESS_CALLBACK(int _iPercent, int _pPrivate);

[DllImportAttribute(@"..\xxx.dll", EntryPoint = "avc_to_avi_convert", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]

public static extern unsafe int avc_to_avi_convert([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder _inputAVC, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder _ouputAVI, int pPrivate, PROGRESS_CALLBACK _pg);

[DllImportAttribute(@"..\xxx.dll", EntryPoint = "avc_to_avi_close", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]

public static extern unsafe void avc_to_avi_close(int pFd_avi);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    StringBuilder inputFile = new StringBuilder(Application.StartupPath + @"\avc\abc.avc");//(@"C:\avc\abc.avc");
    StringBuilder outputFile = new StringBuilder(Application.StartupPath + @"\avi\abc.avi");//(@"C:\avi\abc.avi");

    if (avc_to_avi_convert(
        inputFile,
        outputFile,
        1,
        progress_func) > 0) { 

    }
}

public void progress_func(int iProgress, int pPrivate)
{
     if (iProgress == 100)
     {
         //success
     }
     else if (iProgress == -1)
     {
         //convert error
     }
     else if (iProgress == -2)
     {
         //Not enough disk space
     }
     else
     {
         //update progress
     }
}
```

I changed my code to,

```
[DllImportAttribute(@"..\xxx.dll", EntryPoint = "avc_to_avi_convert", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]

public static extern unsafe int avc_to_avi_convert([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] String _inputAVC, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] String _ouputAVI, int pPrivate, PROGRESS_CALLBACK _pg);

[DllImportAttribute(@"..\xxx.dll", EntryPoint = "avc_to_avi_close", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]

public static extern void avc_to_avi_close(ref int avi);
```

And ran it, and I still get the same error.

Comment: You will need to show us the native C function you are calling (the full signature) along with the C# DLLImport you are using. Without that, there is not enough info to answer this question.

Comment: Hi, feroze. i update this~ thanks a lot~

Comment: Did you get the error even if you chose a small avc file(s)?

Comment: Hi, Amir, i try this avc file is 200kb.. it is too large?

Comment: And i have an error message like this 'Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in TestAVC2AVI.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.'

Comment: And i am see this dll document, it's says when the avc > 2 GB size, it is will cut the avc..

Comment: well the exception is referring to a NULL ptr de-reference error ...
check the passed parameter for NULL value, also check for correct parameter passing, for e,g int * should be ref int in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Are you sure about the calling convention? Try `CallingConvention.StdCall`. Read this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adam_nathan/archive/2003/05/21/56690.aspx

2.) Try a different values for the `CharSet` attribute and use `String` instead of `StringBuilder` for the path arguments. This is a good reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h.aspx

3.) Also, the `avc_to_avi_close` method should look like this:

```
[DllImportAttribute("xxx.dll", EntryPoint="avc_to_avi_close")]
public static extern void avc_to_avi_close(ref int avi);
```

4.) Other things you my want to try:

- Use unusual combinations of `CharSet` and `MarshalAs`. For example you know from the link above that `Unicode` should be used with `LPWStr` and `Ansi` with `LPStr` but you can of course try other combinations.
- Your extern methods need not to be marked `unsafe`.

If you have exhausted all other options, why don't you try to write a C++ program that is analogous to your C# code:

- If it crashes you proved that the error is in the library.
- If it doesn't crash you know the error is in your use of PInovke, and you can go through all the 12+ combinations from my answer one by one.

Comment: Hi, Tilo, i try it in an c++ project, and then have anohter error... like this error C2065: 'progress_func':undeclared identifier, i write the code in funtest.h, see my update.. thank you

Comment: post code in here... int convert_avi(char* pchPath_avc, char* pchPath_avi, void* pUI)
{

 void* pPrivate = NULL;

 int ifd_avi = 0;

 int a = (int)pUI;

 ifd_avi = avc_to_avi_convert(pchPath_avc, pchPath_avi, a, progress_func);
 
 return  ifd_avi;

}

void progress_func(int iProgress, int pPrivate)
{
   if(iProgress == 100){
      //success
   }else if(iProgress == -1){
     //convert error
   }else if(iProgress == -2){
    //Not enough disk space
   }else{
    //update progress
   }  
}

Comment: Thanks Tilo, This helps me a lot ^^

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a delegate to p/invoke and then letting the garbage collector free it.  This causes the crash, because when the delegate object is finalized, the trampoline set up to allow calls from native code is deallocated.  Then the native code invokes a dangling function pointer.

The garbage collector is totally unaware of any objects being used from inside native code.  You MUST keep a reference to the delegate alive for the duration of the call.  Try adding a delegate variable (don't use implicit conversion which creates a temporary) and then use `GCHandle` to keep the delegate alive for as long as the native code is using it.